# Combine 2 regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have the following regular expressions:
The first one extracts the dates with the following pattern XX/XX/XXXX or XX-XX-XXX or XX XX XXX
The second one just extracts the names of the months

```
bool Keywords::extractDate(const char *date)
{
    const boost::regex e("^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])([\\.\\-\\/\\ ])([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])([\\.\\-\\/\\ ])([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$");
    return boost::regex_match(date,e);
}
bool Keywords::extractDate2(const char*date2)
{
    const boost::regex e("((j|J)anvier|(f|F)\u00E9vrier|(f|F)évrier|(f|F)evrier|(m|M)ars|(a|A)vril|(m|M)ai|(j|J)uin|(j|J)uillet|juillet|(a|A)o\u00FBt|(a|A)oût|aout|(s|S)eptembre|(o|O)ctobre|(n|N)ovembre|(d|D)\u00E9cembre|(d|D)écembre|(d|D)ecembre|JANVIER|FEVRIER|MARS|AVRIL|MAI|JUIN|JUILLET|AOUT|SEPTEMBRE|OCTOBRE|NOVEMBRE|DECEMBRE)");
    return boost::regex_match(date2,e);
}///end function
```

Is it possible to combine them?

Thank you.

Comment: Combine them how? Do you want to match both patterns? Either pattern? One pattern in the string followed by the other?

Comment: Does the string you are matching (`XX/XX/XXXX`) contain month names?

Comment: Isn't \u00E9 == é ? BTW, you can improve the regex by factoring out common parts. This improves backtracking. I.e. `Mars|Mai` => `Ma(rs|i)`. This means the regex doesn't have to backtrack when it encounters the i in Mai. Finally, you have a redundant "juillet" but no "Aout".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

Yes you can combine them. This regex will:

- match a date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format where the delimiters can be `.`, `-`, space, or `/`
- allow the year to be either 2 or 4 digits
- if not a `dd-mm-yyyy` format string then search the string for a month name

`^([12][0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9])[-\\\/\s.](1[0-2]|0?[1-9])[-\\\/\s.]([0-9]{2}?[0-9]{2})$|([jJ]anvier|[fF]évrier|[fF]évrier|[fF]evrier|[mM]ars|[aA]vril|[mM]ai|[jJ]uin|[jJ]uillet|[aA]o[éû]t|aout|[sS]eptembre|[oO]ctobre|[nN]ovembre|[dD][eé]cembre|JANVIER|FEVRIER|MARS|AVRIL|MAI|JUIN|JUILLET|AOUT|SEPTEMBRE|OCTOBRE|NOVEMBRE|DECEMBRE)`

Live demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/0i5uIj9ZJX

[image]

I made several slight modifications to your expressions like:

- changing constructs like `(f|F)` to `[fF]`
- removed the unicode characters as I'm not really familure with working with them
- changed the date matching to push the `0?[1-9]` to the end to prevent accidentally matching this alternation first.
- changed constructs like `[1|2]` to `[12]`

Note I had to remove the Unicode characters to make it work for my system. I don't use accented unicode so I'm not really sure how they work as escaped strings in a regex.